# Problems when trying to get Instagram stories through the API

Tags: java, instagram

I have a problem.

Recently, Instagram made a new feature called "Instagram stories" and it seems that they allow you to get the stories of each user.

It is described here:

> Blockquote
>   To get the list of Stories, simply make a GET request to:
>   https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/
>   This endpoint returns all the data associated with the “tray” or bar at the top of your feed with all your friends’ profile pictures.
>   Now, what about authentication? This is where those sweet cookies  come in. Instagram’s desktop website saves cookies about your session to authenticate your requests. 
>   Blockquote

But everytime I try to send session cookies(I am using cookies of my own instagram account) Instagram returns me in response "Login_Required". No matter how I tried.

For e.g. I tried to add these cookies to headers and make a request using Java:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/");

get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("ds_user_id", "6576149574");
BasicClientCookie cookie2 = new BasicClientCookie("sessionid", "IGSC484a13346681fb6ee5ba32114e491c6efc66015f812908156b1c1334cb49387d");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie2);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

Does anybody knows - how to deal with that kind of a problem?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did your forget to set your `cookieStore`?

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```